# General toolbox for creating a travel search engine

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby

As fun learning project, I would like to make a website that synthesizes travel data, similar to this one: http://www.fromatob.com

I am curious if anyone on here has ever done this before and could recommend a general toolbox for which framework to use, etc.

I am a junior developer and have very basic experience working in C# and Ruby. My plugin tells me that fromatob.com uses a combination of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Ruby on Rails. The owners likely had to create partnerships with most of the travel companies (like Megabus UK and expedia) in order to get the APIs for these businesses.

What framework would you recommend for starting on a project like this? I am a lot more comfortable in C#, but everyone seems to suggest that Ruby on Rails would be a lot easier. I don't know enough about the construction to know all of the tools I will need for this project. Any advice? I think this sort of information would be beneficial for a lot of people, as it is difficult to find tutorials online.

Comment: what plugin tells you "that fromatob.com uses a combination of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Ruby on Rails" ?

Comment: It's called Wappalizer. It can only take a guess at which back end language is being used but it is often fairly accurate. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg

Answer (score 0):

The server-side framework (C# vs Ruby on Rails) will not matter so much as the partner you integrate with. Check out [ProgrammableWeb's list of travel APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/travel/apis?category=19965) for an idea of what's out there. If you're more familiar with C#, it would make sense to use that for your site. If you want to learn something new, feel free to try Ruby on Rails (I highly recommend it), but don't think that you have to in order to make a travel site.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only useful answer anyone has ever given me on this website. :D Hopefully I'll also find someone who has made one of these engines and can give me more specifics.